# How to set border-radius to ant design Select component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using ant design and I want to change border-radius of Select component but it is not working. The code is below. And i tried to classname method but it doesn't work.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Select } from 'antd'
const { Option } = Select;

const Dropdown = ({placeholder ,...restProps}) => {
 return (
 <Select
    style={style}
    {...restProps}
    placeholder={placeholder}
 >
 </Select>
 )
}

const style = {
 width: 450,
 borderRadius: '10px',
 margin:3
}
export default Dropdown;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you inspect the element you could find that the `style` is going to the div with classname `ant-select`. But the border is set in the inner div element with classname `ant-select-selector`.

Ant Design doesnt give any prop to override the style for it, but you can override by using CSS.

you can wrap with a custom div and provide CSS to override the style set by ant.
Example,

```
 <div className="my-select-container">
    <Select
     style={style}
     {...restProps}
     placeholder={placeholder}
    >
    </Select>
 </div>
```

and in CSS file,

```
.my-select-container .ant-select .ant-select-selector {
  border-radius:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit hacky but works quite nice.

1. Set `bordered={false}` in the select component (will remove the default border)
2. Apply the following style to the select field:

```css
.borderedSelect {
  border-radius: 10px !important;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;

 
  &:hover {
    border-color: #356796 !important;
    border-top-color: rgb(53, 103, 150);
    border-right-color: rgb(53, 103, 150);
    border-bottom-color: rgb(53, 103, 150);
    border-left-color: rgb(53, 103, 150);
  }
}
```